# Why isn't my LWC passing the values on submit to my apex class?

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning-design-system, lightning-web-components

I've created an lwc that is called in a flow, but when I run it the form doesn't submit and the values aren't passing to the apex class. I can't figure out why.

The form allows me to populate the fields when I run it from the opportunity, but when I click complete it doesn't do anything and I'm not seeing any errors in the console.

JS

```
import {LightningElement, api, track, wire} from 'lwc';
import insertPaymentVaultData from '@salesforce/apex/getAutoCreditCardACHInfo.insertPaymentVaultData';
import { createRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { OPPORTUNITY } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';


export default class Autopay extends LightningElement {
@api recordId;
paymentvaultid;

@api
firstName = '';

@api
lastName = '';

address1 = '';
address2 = '';
city = '';
state = 'TX';
zipCode = '';
country = 'United States';
@api
set address(data) {
    const adr = typeof data === 'string' ? JSON.parse(data) : data;
    this.address1 = adr.address || '';
    this.address2 = adr.address2 || '';
    this.city = adr.city || '';
    this.state = adr.state || '';
    this.zipCode = adr.postal_code || '';
    this.country = adr.country || '';
}
get address() {
    return {
        name: `${this.firstName || ''} ${this.lastName || ''}`.trim(),
        address1: this.address1,
        address2: this.address2,
        city: this.city,
        state: this.state,
        postalCode: this.zipCode,
        country: this.country,
    };
}

accountNumber = '';
abaNumber = '';
bankName = '';
accountType = 'bchecking'; // bchecking; bsavings; nbchecking; nbsavings; echeck

handleFirstNameChange(event) {
    this.firstName = event.target.value;
}
handleLastNameChange(event) {
    this.lastName = event.target.value;
}
handleAbaChange(event) {
    this.abaNumber = event.target.value;
}
handleBankNameChange(event) {
    this.bankName = event.target.value;
}
handleAccountChange(event) {
    this.accountNumber = event.target.value;
}
handleAccountTypeChange(event) {
    this.accountType = event.target.value;
}
handleAddress1Change(event) {
    this.address1 = event.target.value;
}
handleAddress2Change(event) {
    this.address2 = event.target.value;
}
handleCityChange(event) {
    this.city = event.target.value;
}
handleStateChange(event) {
    this.state = event.target.value;
}
handleZipCodeChange(event) {
    this.zipCode = event.target.value;
}
handleCountryChange(event) {
    this.country = event.target.value;
}

validUSRouting(number) {
    if (!number || number.length !== 9) {
        return false;
    }
    let p1 = 0;
    let p2 = 0;
    let p3 = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < number.length; i += 3) {
        p1 += ((+number[i]) * 3);
        p2 += ((+number[i + 1]) * 7);
        p3 += (+number[i + 2]);
    }
    const checkSum = p1 + p2 + p3;
    return (checkSum !== 0) && ((checkSum % 10) === 0);
}

validateInput() {
    // required fields
    const fields = ['lastName', 'accountType', 'accountNumber', 'abaNumber', 'bankName', 'address1', 'city', 'state', 'zipCode', 'country'];
    const missingFields = fields.filter(f => !this[f]);
    if (missingFields.length) {
        return `Required fields ${missingFields.join(', ')} are missing`;
    }
    // aba schema
    if (this.country.toLowerCase() === 'united states' && !this.validUSRouting(this.abaNumber)) {
        return `Invalid US ABA number`;
    }
}

handleFormSubmission() {
    if (this._submitted) {
        return;
    }
    const err = this.validateInput();
    if (err) {
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('error', {
            detail: {
                message: err,
            }
        }));
        return;
    }
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('result', {
        detail: {
            billingAddress : this.address1,
            billingAddress2 : this.address2,
            billingCity : this.city,
            billingZipCode : this.zipCode,
            billingState : this.state,
            autoPaymentType :  'ach',
            ACHABANumber : this.abaNumber,
            ACHAccountNumber : this.accountNumber,
            ACHBankName : this.bankName,
            BankAccountType : this.accountType,

        }
    }));
insertpaymentvault({ 
        creditCardNumber : '', 
        cardType : '',   
        chaseToken :  '',
        expirationYear : '',
        expirationMonth : '',
        fullNameOnCard :  '',
        billingAddress : this.address1,
        billingAddress2 : this.address2,
        billingCity : this.city,
        billingZipCode : this.zipCode,
        billingState : this.state,
        autoPaymentType :  'ach',
        ACHABANumber : this.abaNumber,
        ACHAccountNumber : this.accountNumber,
        ACHBankName : this.bankName,
        BankAccountType : this.accountType, 
    });
    this._submitted = true;
}

_submitted;
get buttonText() {
    return this._submitted ? 'Finished': 'Complete';
}
}
```

HTML

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Account Type: </label>
            <select onchange={handleAccountTypeChange}>
                <option value="bchecking">Checking</option>
                <option value="bsaving">Savings</option>
                <option value="nbchecking">Business Checking</option>
                <option value="nbsavings">Business Savings</option>
                <option value="echeck">eCheck</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Account Number: </label>
            <input type="text" value={accountNumber} onchange={handleAccountChange}>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>ABA (Routing) Number: </label>
            <input type="text" value={abaNumber} onchange={handleAbaChange}>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Bank Name: </label>
            <input type="text" value={bankName} onchange={handleBankNameChange}>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
            <label>First Name: </label>
            <input type="text" value={firstName} onchange={handleFirstNameChange}>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Last Name: </label>
            <input type="text" value={lastName} onchange={handleLastNameChange}>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Street Address: </label>
            <input type="text" value={address1} onchange={handleAddress1Change}>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Address Line 2: </label>
            <input type="text" value={address2} onchange={handleAddress2Change}>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>City: </label>
            <input type="text" value={city} onchange={handleCityChange}>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>State: </label>
            <input type="text" value={state} onchange={handleStateChange}>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Country: </label>
            <input type="text" value={country} onchange={handleCountryChange}>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Zip Code</label>
            <input type="text" value={zipCode} onchange={handleZipCodeChange}>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group input-group-submit">
            <button class="submit-btn" onclick={handleFormSubmission}>{buttonText}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Meta

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>50.0</apiVersion>
    <description>Save payment information for cc or ach into the payment vault.</description>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>autopay</masterLabel>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <objects>
                <object>Opportunity</object>
            </objects>
        </targetConfig>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
            <property name="recordId" type="String" label="Opportunity Id"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Apex Class

```
global with sharing class getAutoCreditCardACHInfo {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Object getCreditCardFromChaseTokenObject(String AccountId){
       
       Account Acct = [
         Select Id,Payment_Vault_Id__c
          FROM Account
         Where Id = :AccountId
      ]; 
        
       List<PaymentVault__c> paymentvault = new List<PaymentVault__c>(); 
       paymentvault = [
         SELECT
            id,
            Credit_Card_Number__c, 
            Card_Type__c,                 
            CC_Expiration_Year__c,
            CC_Expiration_Month__c,
            FullNameOnCard__c,
            BillingAddress__c,
            BillingAddress2__c,
            BillingCity__c,
            BillingZipcode__c,
            BillingState__c,
            ACH_ABANumber__c,
            ACH_AccountNumber__c,
            ACH_BankName__c,
            AutoPaymentType__c
        FROM PaymentVault__c 
        WHERE id = :Acct.Payment_Vault_Id__c            
     ];   
            
        if(!paymentvault.isEmpty()){
            return paymentvault; 
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }       
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static string insertPaymentVaultData(
        String creditCardNumber, 
        String cardType,   
        String chaseToken,
        String expirationYear,
        String expirationMonth,
        String fullNameOnCard,
        String billingAddress,
        String billingAddress2,
        String billingCity,
        String billingZipCode,
        String billingState,
        String autoPaymentType,
        String ACHABANumber,
        String ACHAccountNumber,
        String ACHBankName,
        String BankAccountType
    ){
              
        PaymentVault__c paymentvault = new PaymentVault__c(); 
        
        paymentvault.Credit_Card_Number__c = creditCardNumber; 
        paymentvault.Card_Type__c = cardType ;          
        paymentvault.CC_Expiration_Year__c = expirationYear;
        paymentvault.CC_Expiration_Month__c = expirationMonth;
        paymentvault.FullNameOnCard__c = fullNameOnCard;
        paymentvault.BillingAddress__c = billingAddress;
        paymentvault.BillingAddress2__c = billingAddress2;
        paymentvault.BillingCity__c = billingCity;
        paymentvault.BillingZipcode__c = billingZipCode;
        paymentvault.BillingState__c = billingState; 
        paymentvault.AutoPaymentType__c = autoPaymentType; 
        paymentvault.ACH_ABANumber__c = ACHABANumber; 
        paymentvault.ACH_AccountNumber__c = ACHAccountNumber; 
        paymentvault.ACH_BankName__c = ACHBankName; 
        paymentvault.Bank_Account_Type__c = BankAccountType; 
        
        Insert paymentvault;                
        system.debug('paymentvault.Id: ' + paymentvault.Id);
        return paymentvault.Id;        
    }
}
```

Comment: your Apex mehod name is insertpaymentvaultData not insertpaymentvault. can you check?

Comment: @Himanshu I changed that, thank you for noticing. It still won't submit anything though.

Comment: Where is `insertPaymentVaultData` method being called from LWC? I see you have imported it, but where have you called it?

Comment: @NagendraSingh it's called in the handleFormSubmission.

Comment: I tried with you given example and it does submit all the values to backend after renaming `insertpaymentvault` to `insertPaymentVaultData` in `JS`. The only time it didn't submit was when it fails the validation you have put before firing the apex method. Check if you validation passes.